# How to know that remote bluetooth socket is already connected?

Tags: android, sockets, android-bluetooth

My application communicates with the remote device using `bluetooth` socket.

It connects and data transfers.

But if remote device is already connected to some other device then my socket connect() blocks the UI and does not recover. It hangs and I have to force stop the application to get it worked again.

**From Bluetooth API** -

> ```
> public void connect () 
>
> Added in API level 5
> Attempt to connect to a remote device.
> ```
>
> This method will block until a connection is made or the connection
>   fails.
>
> If this method returns without an exception then this socket is now connected.

So I wonder there may be a situation when the connection neither fails nor connects but is in the middle for the duration long enough that can be bad for user's point of view.

How to handle such a situation ?

I thought about timer but Is there anything better then just a workaround.

Comment: `connect()` blocks the UI anyway. Don't perform network operations on the Ui thread.

Comment: @EJP - This whole process of `connect()` is in a non-UI thread. But I am displaying a Progress Dialog (`"Please Wait..","Connecting to device"`) at `onPreExecute()` and this dialog is only closed at `onPostExecute()` i.e. after doing `connect()` work in the background. The UI hangs at `"Please Wait..","Connecting to device"` which keeps on showing and never ends.